# Difference between ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api and REST classic services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rest

I saw that `ASP.Net MVC4 WebApi` exposes services as a Rest ones.

But what is actually the difference between normal `Rest` and `ASP.Net MVC4 WebApi`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by `normal Rest`.

[REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is a paradigm.

HTTP is a protocol that follows that paradigm.

ASP.NET Web API allows developers to write ASP.NET applications that can be accessed via HTTP and adhere to the REST paradigm. While you could create a REST API without Web API, Web API provides a ton of features that will remove a lot of the pain associated with creating a truly RESTful API in ASP.NET.

[apigee](http://apigee.com/about/resources) has many great resources for REST API best practicies.

Comment: Martin Fowler provides a [good overview](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) of what it means for an application to fully implement the REST architectural style.

Comment: Right, you can create Non-RESTful or RESTful services with WebAPI

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about the general REST standard or the way that REST has been done traditionally on the Microsoft platform prior to the MVC4 Web API? I am thinking you are approaching this as the second one.

The updated approach in MVC4 gives you more REST capabilities without the WCF model. Here is a recent post on the subject: http://mattmilner.com/Milner/Blog/post/2012/02/28/WebAPI-or-WCF.aspx.