# Difference between web API and rest API

Tags: ios, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

Can anyone please explain me what is the difference between web api and rest api in mvc.I am supposed to create an ios application in xamarin using restful services. But i am having some doubts regarding web api and rest api.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685019/difference-between-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-and-rest-classic-services

Comment: see this link2 http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/38691/difference-between-web-api-and-web-service